# Angular 6 : Dynamic Meta tag is not working when sharing page on facebook using og:description tag

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular5, angular6, meta-tags

I want to set dynamic information in meta tag using API call. When I check by inspect, it will show updated data but when I share the link on Facebook it will not reflect updated data.

Index.html

```
  <meta name="description" content="Create and share your biography">
  <meta name="og:url" content="window.location.href"> 
  <meta name="og:title" content="TEACHERLIFE -SPANISH LESSONS">
  <meta name="og:description" content="So I’m in my classroo...">
```

In component.ts :

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 constructor(private metaService: MetaService,
    private meta: Meta,) {}
  ngOnInit() {
this.meta.updateTag( {name: 'og:description', content:"testdescription"});
}
```

Comment: Are you using ssr with your angular application ?

Comment: @FahimUddin No we are not using ssr, we are using client-side angular.

Comment: you have to use ssr, without ssr it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Share doesnot parse the javascript, so it only intercept the static metadata on index.html page.

Please refer to full discussion in github community.

https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-update-meta/issues/13

Comment: Your problem will be resolved if you use server-side rendering, SSR allows you to generate each page resolved by Server. Thus crawler will capture the metatag on rendering rather than javascript update your metatag on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, angular does not use server side rendering. For SEO purpose, you need to add Angular Universal in your project so that server side rendering gets enabled. Then SEO meta tags will work.

https://angular.io/guide/universal

Below is the YouTube tutorial which I came across which explains the concept.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lncsmB5yfzE

Answer (score -2):

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private meta: Meta) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.meta.updateTag(
     {name: 'twitter:title', content:'Front-end Web Development'},
     `name='twitter:title'`
   );
}
```

Comment: This does NOT work!! See the first answer for why. Facebook and other websites call your page and only see the tags defined in index.html and somehow the meta tags that are updated with updateTag are ignored.